# PHP selectively includes part of a file

Tags: php, html, include

OK, so on some of the pages on my site, I've included a foot.php file at the end so that when I make changes to it, it effects all pages on the site. On most pages, this works perfectly, but on some pages, it just cuts off, and no includes after it take effect. The weird thing is that it includes only a portion of the file on pages where this happens.

I thought it might be because of the number of includes I used, but I have pages with more that work just fine. Take for instance, this one:

http://www.kelvinshadewing.net/codeSquirrel5.php

Here, you can see the bottom gets cut off, and if you view the source code, the rest of what goes in that div is gone, yet the div itself is closed off properly. But then go here:

http://www.kelvinshadewing.net/sprTartii.php

You'll see that the full code is there, and the Disqus app is present as well. This issue has been going on since before I added Disqus, and also happened when I'd been using includes in a different way to generate global content, so it's something about those pages in particular. It does it with only my Squirrel tutorials, and nothing else. I'm totally stumped and have no idea what's causing this. I've gone over my code a dozen times, and verified that every page uses the same PHP scripts.

As for the scripts themselves, it's just this:

```
<?php include "foot.php";
include "disqus.php"; ?>
```

Comment: This could happen if you have php errors and your server is hiding the error output. It will stop any subsequent php from executing. Try adding this to top of the very first php file and see if there are any errors that need fixing: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Note this will show errors to all your users.

Comment: Odd, I went to try what you said, and the problem just... disappeared. 0.-.0 It's all working perfectly now. Even the test page I copied from one of the bad pages is working fine and doesn't report any errors. I'm wondering if maybe there was just a server glitch or something.

Comment: Yea that is weird. Maybe it was a server glitch as you said. Does it work without the code I told you to use?

Comment: Yeah, works without it, too. Probably just a server glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem just disappeared, so I'm ruling it as a server glitch. If anyone else is reading this, I suggest checking out Andrew's comment, because that code was nice to know.